# how to set \mathversion{bold} in unicode-math.sty

Tags: unicode-math

I am using a style file unicode-math.sty and the compiler is lualatex

1. i need lower and upper alphabets and numbers, and punctuations from Times font,
2. upper/lower greek characters and math symbols from latinmodern-math.otf/Stix font

i am trying to fix through `\setmathfont{TimesLTStd-Italic.otf}[version=normal,` `\setmathfont{TimesLTStd-Italic.otf}[version=bold,`

but the output not producing as expected, when using \mathversion{normal} producing bold output, how to get the bold and normal version through unicode-math

also when suing `version` \left and \right delimiters are not working

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{unicode-math}


\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
             ItalicFont = TimesLTStd-Italic.otf,
             BoldFont = TimesLTStd-Bold.otf,
             BoldItalicFont = TimesLTStd-BoldItalic.otf,NFSSFamily=Times
            ]{TimesLTStd-Roman.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont{TimesLTStd-Italic.otf}[version=normal,range=it/{latin,Latin}]
\setmathfont{TimesLTStd-Roman.otf}[version=normal,range=up/{num}]
%
\setmathfont{TimesLTStd-BoldItalic.otf}[version=bold,range=it/{latin,Latin}]
\setmathfont{TimesLTStd-Bold.otf} [version=bold,  range=up/{num}]


\begin{document}

{\mathversion{normal}$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$}

{\mathversion{bold}$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$}

$$\left(\frac{120^{addass}}{1233_{dasassa}}\right)$$

\end{document}
```